# Socket stream does not contain entire response

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, stream

I have some socket communication in my c# application.  The client sends a request (an XML string) to the server, and the server responds back with another XML string.

The following is the code running on the client:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(socket.HostName, socket.Port))
{
    client.SendBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    client.ReceiveBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
    sw.AutoFlush = true;

    sw.WriteLine(requests.ToXML());

    List<string> xmlStrings = new List<string>();
    while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        xmlStrings.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    string xmlStr = string.Join("\r\n", xmlStrings.ToArray());

    ProcessXMLResponse(xmlStr);

    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
}
```

And this runs on the server machine:

```
using (Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;

    List<string> xmlStrings = new List<string>();
        while (sr.Peek() > -1)
    xmlStrings.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    string xmlStr = string.Join("\r\n", xmlStrings.ToArray());
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(xmlStr);

    string responseXML = ProcessXMLRequest(xml);

    sw.WriteLine(response);
    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    stream.Close();
}
```

This code seems to work most of the time, but sometimes (maybe when the XML response is large?), the client seems to only receive the first part of the XML reply.  The sr.Peek() call returns -1 even though the data would have not all been received yet.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: It could be because the data hasn't been fully sent / received yet. Try sending the length in advance and wait until socket.Available == length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at [`StreamReader.Peek` in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek(v=vs.110).aspx):

> An integer representing the next character to be read, or -1 if there are no characters to be read **or if the stream does not support seeking**.

(emphasis mine)

`NetworkStream` [is not seekable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a value that indicates whether the stream supports seeking ... This property always returns false.

Basically, according to the docs, your code is broken; I'm guessing it is working when there is data readily available (which would be consistent with the small vs large payload description), but fails when the data is not immediately available.

Basically, don't use `Peek` here. Just read the data until you run out of it. If you want to minimise the code changes:

```
List<string> xmlStrings = new List<string>();
string line;
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    xmlStrings.Add(line);
```

Personally I would implement it very differently, though.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try using

```
sr.ReadToEnd()
```

instead of

```
sr.ReadLine()
```

in both sides?

Also, as a word of advice, you should put more effort into efficiently disposing of your resources:

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(socket.HostName, socket.Port))
{
    client.SendBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    client.ReceiveBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

    Stream stream = client.GetStream();
    //generally, you should avoid calling Dispose() on an object multiple times

    //don't put this in a using block as that implicitly calls Dispose() which internally calls Dispose on the stream as well
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

    //don't put this in a using block as that implicitly calls Dispose() which internally calls Dispose on the stream as well
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    sw.WriteLine("test");

    List<string> xmlStrings = new List<string>();
    while (sr.Peek() > -1)
        xmlStrings.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    string xmlStr = string.Join("\r\n", xmlStrings.ToArray());

    //this calls stream.Dispose as well internally
    sr.Close();

    //actually, this also calls stream.Dispose(), but fortunately MS made it safe
    sw.Close();

    ProcessXMLResponse(xmlStr);
}

//At this point all IDisposable objects have been disposed of properly (TcpClient, Stream, StreamReader, StreamWriter)
//we minimized the number of stream.Dispose() calls whereas using 3 using blocks (1 for the stream, 1 for the Reader and 1 for the Writer) would have resulted in 3 calls
```

Comment: ReadToEnd doesn't seem to be supported on this, and it blocks indefinitely.